# email change data does not appear

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

when I make a change update the email data does not appear and does not enter the database.

this is the display when you want to make changes to the data.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lJ47B.jpg

this is the display when I have made changes, the email does not enter the database and does not appear

https://i.stack.imgur.com/sleTG.jpg

this is the code for updating data in file siswa.php

```
$(document).on('click', '.ubah_siswa', function() {
    siswa_id = $(this).attr('id');
    clear_field();
    $.ajax({
        url: "siswa_action.php",
        method: "POST",
        data: {
            action: 'edit_fetch',
            siswa_id: siswa_id
        },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
            $('#nama_siswa').val(data.nama_siswa);
            $('#kelas_siswa').val(data.kelas_siswa);
            $('#siswa_peminatan_id').val(data.siswa_peminatan_id);
            $('#email_siswa').val(data.email_siswa);
            $('#error_foto_siswa').html('<img src="foto_siswa/' + data.foto_siswa + '" class="img-thumbnail" width="50" />');
            $('#hidden_foto_siswa').val(data.foto_siswa);
            $('#siswa_id').val(data.siswa_id);
            $('#modal_title').text("Ubah Data siswa");
            $('#button_action').val('Ubah');
            $('#action').val('Ubah');
            $('#formModal').modal('show');
        }
    });
});
```

this is the code for updating data in file siswa_action.php

```
if ($_POST["action"] == "Ubah") {
    $data = array(
                ':nama_siswa'                =>    $nama_siswa,
                ':kelas_siswa'            =>    $kelas_siswa,
                ':siswa_peminatan_id'            =>    $siswa_peminatan_id,
                ':email_siswa'            =>    $email_siswa,
                ':foto_siswa'            =>    $foto_siswa,
                ':siswa_id'                =>    $_POST["siswa_id"]
            );
    $query = "UPDATE tbl_siswa 
                SET nama_siswa = :nama_siswa, 
                kelas_siswa = :kelas_siswa,
                foto_siswa = :foto_siswa, 
                email_siswa = :email_siswa, 
                siswa_peminatan_id = :siswa_peminatan_id
                WHERE siswa_id = :siswa_id
                ";
    $statement = $connect->prepare($query);
    if ($statement->execute($data)) {
        $output = array(
            'success'        =>    'Data Berhasil Diubah',
        );
    }
}

if ($_POST["action"] == "edit_fetch") {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_siswa WHERE siswa_id = '" . $_POST["siswa_id"] . "'";
    $statement = $connect->prepare($query);
    if ($statement->execute()) {
        $result = $statement->fetchAll();
        foreach ($result as $row) {
            $output['nama_siswa'] = $row['nama_siswa'];
            $output['kelas_siswa'] = $row['kelas_siswa'];
            $output['email_siswa'] = $row['email_siswa'];
            $output['siswa_peminatan_id'] = $row['siswa_peminatan_id'];
            $output['foto_siswa'] = $row['foto_siswa'];
            $output['siswa_id'] = $row['siswa_id'];
        }
        echo json_encode($output);
    }
}
```

for full code in here, https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-dust-fjusz?fontsize=14

I've tried to search for what's wrong, maybe here someone knows the error where, can be checked in the full code for details

Comment: What _does_ happen?  What debugging have you already done to narrow down the problem?

Comment: Your edit only happens when the action is `Ubah`, but you're passing in  `edit_fetch`, which only retrieves the data. Where's the Ajax code for when the action is `Ubah`?

Comment: all data is successfully changed except e-mail, the previous module uses the ajax code listed above successfully. only email doesn't work.

Comment: You're going to have to dig a bit. `var_dump($data);` after you create it for insert: does it contain what you expect? If not, `var_dump($_POST);`: does that contain the email address?